# Turn off ALL "invited you to play" notifications on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

On Facebook, how can I get rid of **ALL** "User X has invited you to play Game Y" from showing up in my Facebook notifications, without having to block/unfriend each and every app/user?

I have seen [this post](http://danamnelson.com/tired-of-getting-facebook-game-request-notifications/) which essentially says to do the following:

1. Open Facebook on the Desktop.
2. Click on the Notifications icon (globe).
3. Click the X next to the notification.
4. Click "Turn Off" when it asks you "Turn off notifications from [annoying game]?"
5. Bonus step (optional): Report the app for spam.

The problem with this approach:

- There is no way to do this on the Facebook iPhone app, so I must go to the desktop (or mobile Safari) and perform this manual process.
- I don't want to block individual apps from notifications. There are hundreds of these apps popping up all the time. Today it is Candy Crush, FarmVille and Cash King, tomorrow it's gonna be Candy Smash, FarmValley, and Money Queen. Why is the burden on me, the user, to swat these pesky apps one-by-one as though they are flies?
- I don't want to block individual users from notifications, nor unfriend them. Again, today it is user X, Y, and Z, tomorrow it's gonna be A, B, and C.
- If you make a mistake, there is no way to undo it once you refresh that screen. Nowhere in the "Notifications Settings" screen do I see a list of all the apps I have blocked nor a way to undo all of them, let alone undo an individual one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do what you're asking to do, and likely will not be. Facebook's customization options are deceptively sparse, and they intentionally limit user usability in order to maintain more direct control over the content users are exposed to. There is a surprising lack of other obvious features, in (for example) Newsfeed options, like the option to only show posts made by friends, not displaying as major items posts that they like or are merely tagged in.

Mack nordstrum mentioned the settings at "https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking". This will solve a few of the problems you mentioned, but requires you to individually specify either specific friends whom you want to block ALL app invites from, or select the individual apps themselves to block or unblock. An option to block all from the get-go, regardless of user, before you ever get your first invite at all, is unlikely to be made available because it conflicts so strongly with Facebook's business model. To answer your question of why the burden is on you, the user, to swat these pesky apps one-by-one: You, the user, are not the one paying facebook money. The creators of those apps are.

Answer (score 0):

You can block friends from inviting you to games /apps, see here:
https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking
On that page you can choose people whose game/app invites you dont want to receive.
The page also lists all the games/apps you have blocked, and allows you to add games to your block list.